# Alpine package install protocol error

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to install git on alpine `3.6`. It is failing with `Protocol error` in the first instance but works on the second instance. To be specific `pcre` and `libcurl` are not installed in first instance. Here's the log of what I am trying to do.

```
$ docker run -it alpine:3.6 /bin/sh
/ # apk --update add git
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing ca-certificates (20161130-r2)
(2/6) Installing libssh2 (1.8.0-r1)
(3/6) Installing libcurl (7.56.1-r0)
ERROR: libcurl-7.56.1-r0: Protocol error
(4/6) Installing expat (2.2.0-r1)
(5/6) Installing pcre (8.41-r0)
ERROR: pcre-8.41-r0: Protocol error
(6/6) Installing git (2.13.5-r0)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20161130-r2.trigger
2 errors; 24 MiB in 15 packages
/ # git
Error loading shared library libpcre.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/bin/git)
Error relocating /usr/bin/git: pcre_compile: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/git: pcre_exec: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/git: pcre_maketables: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/git: pcre_study: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/git: pcre_free: symbol not found
```

Installing `pcre`/`git` again works though.

```
/ # apk add pcre
(1/2) Installing libcurl (7.56.1-r0)
(2/2) Installing pcre (8.41-r0)
OK: 25 MiB in 17 packages
/ # git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask about Alpine and `apk` package issues.

Comment: @matt Docker really makes the separation between development and operations murky. I'm sure the person who asked above is a developer and installing packages in docker containers is now part of the normal development workflow.

Comment: @Alkaline no doubt they are, I'm just not sure that adding a container makes it a SO question. Questions about installing package's on a host or installing packages on a VM would be OT.  Installing packages in a container seems largely the same to me. Docker's a bit tricky generally as it straddles so much space

Comment: @Matt I would rather look at it from a developer point of view. Is this question relevant to the majority of SO users (developers). With containers, I'd say yes. I'm not voting this one down. It's a murky area as we both agree on.

Comment: Worked fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, now it's working fine. Seems like alpine repository issue.

Comment: Yes, this was a temporary problem with dl-cdn. I recommend to use one of the normal mirrors (see https://mirrors.alpinelinux.org/) instead of dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org which unfortunately quite often does not work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too (surprisingly, it was deterministic), and changing the mirror worked. For example, do:

```
$ echo "https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/alpine/v3.7/main" >/etc/apk/repositories
$ echo "https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/alpine/v3.7/community" >>/etc/apk/repositories
```

to change the mirror to the UWaterloo server. You can find the full list of mirrors [here](https://mirrors.alpinelinux.org/).